# WPF Context Menu with dropdown list showing hyperlinks

Tags: wpf

I know how to create the context menu in xaml with the code behind in C#. What I cannot find is how to have a menu item that when clicked will display a list with each item in the list being a hyperlink to other websites. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can achieve this purely by MVVM.

XAML:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="SubMenuItemTemplate">
        <ContentControl>
            <Hyperlink>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/> //Here you can bind to your site address property
            </Hyperlink>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SubMenuItems}"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SubMenuItemTemplate}"/>
    </Style>

    <ContextMenu x:Key="myContextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}">
```

You can set `ContextMenu` property of any control to myContextMenu to use this.
C# class

```
public class ContextMenuItem
{
    public string Name
    { get; set; }

    public List<String> SubMenuItems
    { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel can have property ContextMenuItems i.e collection of ContextMenuItems.

Hope this will help

Thanks