# Add a descriptive MenuItem to a WPF ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, menuitem

I am trying to add an item to a WPF-`ContextMenu` that is only used to "describe" the items below but I am not sure how to add a simple line of text above all the items, where the text is centrally aligned and the text is not selectable like the normal `MenuItem`s.

I tried something like this:

```
<ContextMenu Grid.Row="0" StaysOpen="False">
    <TextBlock Text="Add New:" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    <MenuItem Header="one"/>
    <MenuItem Header="two (horizontal)"/>
    <MenuItem Header="two (vertical)"/>
    <MenuItem Header="three"/>
    <MenuItem Header="four"/>
    <MenuItem Header="six"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

but unfortunately the TextBlock is neither aligned centrally, nor is it unselectable.
The problem is that using a `MenuItem` and setting the `IsEnabled`-property to false, the text is not normal black anymore and also I can't really align it centrally.

Hopefully, someone can think of a easy solution here, I simply couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to create the SubMenu items for menuitems. In this way menuitems will group all the submenuitems under it.

I had given the answer to create the context menu with menuitem and submenuitems purely using mvvm. Here you can refer to it.

[WPF Context Menu with dropdown list showing hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518198/wpf-context-menu-with-dropdown-list-showing-hyperlinks/18518845#18518845)

OR For the case you mentioned. I tried this:

```
     <ContextMenu StaysOpen="False">
                        <MenuItem Header="Add New:" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <MenuItem.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>

                            </MenuItem.Style>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="one"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="two (horizontal)"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="two (vertical)"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="three"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="four"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="six"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
```

and I got menu like 
[image]

Add New: is non-selectable and also mouse over does not highlight it.

Hope it helps. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this doesn't look like a direct solution of my problem. I will consider this solution, if the descriptive item idea has no was of working.

Comment: I updated the answer with other option also. See if it helps you. Thanks